# Retrieve feature level tags in Specflow

Tags: c#, tags, specflow, gherkin

Is it possible to get **feature** level tags?

I know that you can get scenario level easily by doing

`ScenarioContext.Current.ScenarioInfo.Tags`

Unfortunately that doesn't return all tags that apply to the current scenario.

Answer (score 5):

Found it!

`FeatureContext.Current.FeatureInfo.Tags`